# How to insert data into temp table from a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have one table as the following

Business (BId - BName)

- 1 - ABC
- 2 - DEF
- 3 - GHI
- 4 - JKL

And I created a temporary table

```
Create table #Temp(
TBID int,
TBNAME nvarchar(50)
);
```

Now I have to add the data into #temp from a string like

```
Declare string = 'ABC, GHI'
```

How will I add data into #temp table from the above string with its corresponding Ids in #temp

The output of the table #temp should be like

#temp (TBID - TBNAME

- 1 - ABC
- 3 - GHI

Comment: Actually I have to do all these operations dynamically...

Comment: String has `'ABC, GHI'` but in temp table how come you got `'DEF'`

Comment: 'DEF' doesn't need not to be inserted in #temp table

Comment: You expected Output has `2 -DEF and 3 - GHI`

Comment: yes exactly, these insertion should be made in temp

Comment: oh sorry i have corrected my mistake in the question

Comment: Finally u got my point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.. U need to use `LTRIM and RTRIM` to remove unwanted space at start and end after converting into rows.

```
CREATE TABLE #Business
  (BId   INT,BName VARCHAR(50)
  )

INSERT INTO #Business
VALUES      (1,'ABC'),(2,'DEF'),(3,'GHI'),(4,'JKL')

DECLARE @strng VARCHAR(max) = 'ABC, GHI'

SELECT B.BId   AS TBIB,
       B.BName TBName
INTO   #temp
FROM   (SELECT Rtrim(Ltrim(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'))) AS Data
        FROM   (SELECT Cast ('<M>' + Replace(@strng, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data) AS A
               CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)) a
       JOIN #Business B
         ON a.data = B.BName

SELECT *
FROM   #temp
```

Comment: It's throwing an error Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near 'a'.

Comment: @Nida - check now added with table data

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
DECLARE @S varchar(max),
        @Split char(1),
        @X xml

SELECT @S = 'ABC, GHI',
       @Split = ','

SELECT @X = CONVERT(xml,' <root> <s>' + 
REPLACE(@S,@Split,'</s> <s>') + '</s>   </root> ')


SELECT    [Value] = T.c.value('.','varchar(20)') into #tempTbl  
FROM @X.nodes('/root/s') T(c)

select Bus.ID,tbl.Name from #tempTbl tbl JOIN  Business Bus
on tbl.Value=Bus.BName
```

**OUTPUT**

```
ID  Value 
1   ABC

3   GHI
```

Comment: It doesnot contain any insert operations

Comment: What about their corresponding Id's

Comment: I mean for 'ABC' the BId is 1