# Error in stored procedure while join operation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have written a stored procedure as below

```
 Create table #Temp(
 TLOAID int,
 TLOAName nvarchar(50)
 );

 -- drop table #Temp;
 DECLARE @string VARCHAR(max) = 'Casualty, Insurance, Debit,';
 -- SET @string = @LOAStringParam;

 SELECT B.LOAId  AS TLOAID,
 B.LOAName TLOAName
 INTO   #temp
 FROM (SELECT Rtrim(Ltrim(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'))) AS Data
 FROM (SELECT Cast ('<M>' + Replace(@string, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data) AS A
 CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)) a
 JOIN tbLOA B
 ON a.data = B.LOAName;

 If(exists(SELECT tbPLOA.LOAId
 FROM  tbPLOA
 WHERE tbPLOA.LOAId NOT IN(SELECT #Temp.TLOAID from #Temp) AND PId= @PId))
 BEGIN
 ....

 ....
 END
 ...
```

Now it's throwing error message like

Incorrect syntax near 'a'.

I am not able to trace this error!!! Please help me!!!

Comment: I think your error comes from : CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)) a.   I assume Split is a custom function to split a string?  Perhaps try using more meaning full aliases.  Looks like you have "a" used for multiple purposes.

Comment: @RichardVivian is right

Comment: Can you please explain it in the code

Comment: This code with same alias should run fine. Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26816418/how-to-insert-data-into-temp-table-from-a-string

Comment: I don't think you can use twice the same alias a  and A

Comment: You can use the same alias many times in the same query, as long as its unique in its context.  Eg.  SELECT A.A AS A FROM (SELECT 1 AS A) AS A   is exactly the same as: SELECT B.A AS C FROM (SELECT 1 AS A) AS B.  It just makes more human readable sense to use meaningful names.  Better yet would be:  SELECT Amounts.Amount AS MyAmount FROM (SELECT 1 AS Amount) AS Amounts .   Meaningful names, and breaking complex queries to sub-queries will resolve most syntax errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the alias name like this.

```
CREATE TABLE #Business
  (BId   INT,BName VARCHAR(50)
  )

INSERT INTO #Business
VALUES      (1,'Casualty'),(2,'Insurance'),(3,'Debit'),(4,'JKL')

DECLARE @strng VARCHAR(max) = 'Casualty, Insurance, Debit,'

SELECT B.BId   AS TBIB,
       B.BName TBName
INTO   #temp
FROM   (SELECT Rtrim(Ltrim(Split.sp.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'))) AS Data
        FROM   (SELECT Cast ('<M>' + Replace(@strng, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data) A
               CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(sp)) oo
       JOIN #Business B
         ON oo.data = B.BName 


SELECT *
FROM   #temp
```

Comment: Now It's throwing error Incorrect syntax near 'oo'.

Comment: It works fine in New Query Section (Directly executing the above statement) but not in stored procedure

Comment: @Nida Can you paste the SP in question so that it will be easy to find the error

Comment: try converting my answer into SP it will work fine. There is nothing to say like it wont work in SP.

Comment: Yes you are right but I am not sure why it is not working there

Comment: I removed  Create table #Temp(
 TLOAID int,
 TLOAName nvarchar(50)
 );

Comment: @Nida yes U are using  select into #temp... so no need of create table script.